# How to wait for the api call to finish and then check if element present using cypress?

Tags: cypress

i am new to cypress and i am trying to check if the element exists on a page once the api call is finished.

i do a http post to url 'things/thing1' and once this api finishes i want to check if span element is present on page.

i have tried something like below.

```
const setUp = () => {
    cy.apiPatchSomethings(something1)
        .then(() => {
            cy.reload();
        });
}

describe('Suite name', () => {
    before(() => {
        setUp();
    });
    it('test case', () => {
        cy.contains('span');
    }
});
```

the above code doesnt work. even before span element is seen on page it checks for span element.

if i use cy.wait(10000) like below it works

```
it('test case', () => {
    cy.wait(10000);
    cy.contains('span');
});
```

but i dont want to use cy.wait. is there some other way to solve this. could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: Does `cy.apiPatchSomethings` return a promise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypress command [cy.contains()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains.html#Syntax) when called with a single argument is looking for ***content***,

> **Syntax**
> cy.contains(content)
> cy.contains(content, options)
> cy.contains(selector, content)
> cy.contains(selector, content, options)

but I'm guessing you are looking for a span element, so use

```js
cy.get('span')
```

or

```js
cy.contains('span', 'my-content-in-span')
```

---

**Assuming that's not the problem**, just some arbitrary sample code...

Your can modify the setup function to return a promise, in order to wait for the reload.

```js
const setUp = () => {
  return cy.apiPatchSomethings(something1)     // need a return here
    .then(() => {
      return new Cypress.Promise(resolve => {  // inner return also
        cy.reload()
        resolve(true)                          // resolve will signal reload is finished
      })
    });
}
```

Because `setup()` is invoked inside `before()` Cypress will wait for the promise to resolve before proceeding.

Please don't add extra waits or timeouts, which is too often suggested. This will only lead to flaky tests.

**Note** if you don't mind ditching the `setup()` function, it becomes a lot simpler

```
describe('Suite name', () => {

  before(() => {
    cy.apiPatchSomethings(something1)
      .then(() => cy.reload() );      // all commands here will be completed
                                      // before the tests start
  });

  it('test case', () => {
    cy.contains('span', 'my-content-in-span');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You can wait for `span` to be visible. The default timeout that cypress provides is 4 seconds.

```
cy.contains('span').should('be.visible')
```

2.If you want to give a custom timeout(eg. 10 sec) specific to this command, you can use:

```
cy.contains('span', { timeout: 10000 }).should('be.visible')
```

3.If you want to increase the timeout globally you mention this in your `cypress.json` file:

```
"defaultCommandTimeout": 10000
```

and, then just use:

```
cy.contains('span').should('be.visible')
```

Now, all your commands will have a default timeout for 10 seconds.